# How to redirect user to another page while passing parameters without using cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to redirect users from URLs like `/?v=xxx` to the index without parameters while passing these parameters in some other way to actually use them internally (so I just want to remove the parameters from the address).

The first idea I came up with was the usage of custom headers:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if (req.query.v !== undefined) {
    res.set('Video-ID', req.query.v);
    res.redirect('/');
  } else {
    console.log(req.get('Video-ID'));
    res.render('index', {
      videoID: req.get('Video-ID')
    });
  }
});
```

but it seems that it doesn't work -- `console.log(req.get('Video-ID'));` prints `undefined` every time.

Is there any way to redirect user while passing arguments internally **without** using cookies? If I have to use cookies, what is the best way to do it in Express 4 then?

Comment: use the session if you want to do that, but ... why do you want to do it ?

Comment: Sessions ultimately also work with cookies.

Comment: I usually use local storage, read more about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies

Comment: @robertklep I know, but it didn't seem like he knew what he wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to achieve this.

[cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) is a great tool. Though, you can use [Express's cookies](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie) and they will do what you need.

```
// Before redirect
res.cookie('videoId', '123456789');
// After redirect method
res.clearCookie('videoId');
```